# h:commandLink JSF file download

Tags: file, jsf, download

I am trying to create a download link in a JSF page. The page has many richfaces fields that have validation enabled. Some have validator methods attached to them, some just have the required attribute set to true. The download link is an h:commandlink element. This link is supposed to download a file from the server. When I click on the link, validation on a few fields is triggered. How can I avoid this?

Thanks.

Comment: try adding `immediate=true` to the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the file on the server side. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Either put it in a separate form,

```
<h:form>
    ... other input fields ...
</h:form>
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Download" action="#{bean.download}" />
</h:form>
```

or use `immediate="true"` so that all input fields which do *not* have this attribute set will be skipped in the process

```
<h:commandLink value="Download" action="#{bean.download}" immediate="true" />
```

Comment: Balu & Daniel, I am using the immediate attribute, yet I see the issue. Here is the code:  <h:commandLink id="dlpl" value="Download File" action="#{bb.download}" immediate="true"/>.

Comment: Apparently you're either not using `<h:commandLink>`, but a different component, or you *actually* have put `immediate="true"` on all required input fields as well, or your validation mechanism is kind of odd (i.e. not using standard JSF `Validator`s). Hard to tell without seeing an SSCCE.

Comment: Balu, the layout of the page is such that the link is inside the main form. Creating another form would push it down in the layout and away from other fields that are meaning fully related from a user's point of view.